# How can i open IE without Back Forward buttons

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, controls

I want to open IE without Back Forward buttons using C# Code.Just like this:

[image]

But it shows like this:

[image]

The C# code is:

```
using (WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser())
{
    wb.Url = new System.Uri("about:blank");
    wb.Document.Window.OpenNew(URLStr.ToString(), "location=yes,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,status=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes");
}
```

I wonder where did i go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom form to hold your browser and do not show the browser itself. Please check my sample code which does the same:

[image]

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        WebBrowser webbrowser = new WebBrowser();
        webbrowser.Parent = this;
        webbrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        webbrowser.Navigate("www.google.com");  
    }
}
```

Comment: And if you want to disable navigating back from backspace button, you can add handler to `Navigate` event of `WebBrowser` and block doing so

Comment: This is not the result i want. I don't want to embed it in a winform. I want it look like this:[link]https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNTYr.png

Comment: Well I am afraid MS did not give direct access to back and forward buttons as in MSDN definition of `WebBrowser`. What I show you here is a workaround which you can manipulate yourself based on your needs. You can add icon to the form as IE and add a text box to show the address being navigated to. That way you would get a replica of what you intend to see.

Comment: Thanks, but this workaround doesn't meet my requirement.

Comment: Just a comment! In your code setting `location=yes` causes to show up the complete control with address bar along with back and forward buttons. Ideally, setting `document=no` or `toolbar=no` should show up the result you want. But, it doesn't work that way. If you can defer to show the address bar, you may in a way hide back and forward buttons. Otherwise, I do not see a better solution to your problem.